# WooCommerce lost-password endpoint/url gets replaced with wp-login?action=lostpassword

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have tried several methods but the lost-password is constantly replaced with:

```
wp-login?action=lostpassword
```

It's set in the woocommerce endpoint

I've even added the below in theme functions.php file:

```
add_filter( 'lostpassword_url', 'my_lostpassword_url', 10, 2 );
function my_lostpassword_url( $lostpassword_url, $redirect ) {        
    $redirect = '/my-account/lost-password';
    
    return site_url( '/wp-login.php?action=lostpassword' . $redirect );
}
```

Purged caches yet still, anytime i click on the URL to go to the password reset page, it defaults to `wp-login.php?` which doesn't work and just refreshes the My Account page.

Any help will be much appreciated

Comment: I don't understand why the last line would work, because it's literally redirecting to `'/wp-login.php?action=lostpassword' ...`, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removed this completely, reinstalled WooCommerce and added lost-password to the endpoints within WooCommerce Settings managed to overwrite wordpress settings

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. The problem was from the Maintenance plugin. Although the maintenance mode was off, I deactivated this plugin and it fixed the problem.